# bootstrap onDblClickRow event not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap table and it has function on double click event. On my laptop it works fine, however on the mobile when I try double tap row nothing happens.

CODE:

```
<div class="col-xs-24 main">

  <table id="table-pagination" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th data-field="order_create_date" data-align="center"> Užsakymo data</th>
         <th data-field="order_user_id" data-align="center"> Vartotojas</th>
         <th data-field="order_client_name" data-align="center">Užsakovas</th>      
         <th data-field="order_client_order_number" data-align="center">Užsakovo užsakymo nr</th>
         <th data-field="order_pickup_date" data-align="center">Pasikrovimo data</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <script>
  getorders(function(r) {

    $('#table-pagination').bootstrapTable({
      data: r,
      pagination: true,
      pageList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
      search: true,
      showColumns: true,
      onDblClickRow: function (row, $element) {
        var key = row["key"];        
        window.location.href = "orders/display/"+key;
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</div>
</div>
```

`getorders` is a callback function used to get table data using ajax request

CODE:

```
function getorders(callback) {
  var data = {};
  $.ajax({
    url: "home/get_orders",
    type: "POST",
    data: "",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response) {
      var jsonarray = $.parseJSON(response);
      callback(jsonarray);
    }
  });
}
```

Like I said on desktops and laptops works fine, not sure about tables but on mobiles (androids) not working.

Maybe its `window.location.href = "orders/display/"+key;` not working on mobiles. I have tried adding `return false` below it didn't helped.

Any suggestions?

Comment: no, i had to add it coz it didn't allow me to put code here :))

Comment: That was because you didn't add enough spaces at the beginning of the line, as of that it would not have been rendered as code but a pure html and there `<script>` indeed would not have been valid.

Comment: I don't think that it is related to your problem, but but whenever you request json data, you should not set the `dataType` to `html` (as it is not html). The only valid `dataType` for `json` date beside `json` would be `text`.  If you set it to `json` then you won't need `$.parseJSON(response);`  as `response` will already be the resulting JavaScript object. You could just write `dataType: 'json', success : callback` not need for an additional anonymous function.

Comment: r u sure that your `onDblClickRow` callback is invoked when you double tap on the row ? Just put an alert in the first line and see if that pops up

Comment: Good point, yes its not alerting anything, any suggestions?